# Memory problem after upgrade to El Capitan

Tags: macos, mac, imac

I have an iMac 27 inch ( Late 2013 ) system.It has 8 GB RAM. Today i upgraded to El Captain from Yosemite. El Captain installed successfully. Now it is showing 4 GB Memory. I dont know what happen to remaining 4 GB Memory.

Comment: You may need to reset the SMC : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295.
  Run these commands before and after the SMC reset to check if something did change `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType` and / or `sysctl hw.memsize` . If nothing changed one of your 4GB RAM is dead.

Comment: Have you tried removing and re-inserting the RAM modules? (possibly swapping them)

Comment: Yes. Now it is working...I removed and re-inserted the RAM.

Comment: I got the same problem, memory lost 8GB. reinserted the memory but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I followed the comments and re-inserted the RAM.  I rebooted and the system showed both memory ports full with full RAM.  I even switched the RAM to see if that would reveal any new information.